# Polygon to raster (cell coverage)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion

I'm using Polygon to Raster tool to create a raster (10x10). The problem is that some cells of the output raster is not assigned any value.

My understanding is that the tool always uses the cell center to decide the value of a raster pixel.
Attached is the result when I overlay both the output raster and Input polygon on ArcMap. (Black is the NoData cell).

***Anyway to include all those cells that fall within the polygon when generating the raster?***[image]
I tried to use Feature Vertices to Points to generate the point and convert the points to raster, but the vertex of the polygon that I used only have 1 vertex.

Another item to note is when using smaller cell size (1x1), the raster cell generated are good but when I resample it to 10x10, the output raster from resampling is the same as above raster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can not be eliminated due to quantization error. But you can expand your rasterized polygons using [Expand (Spatial Analyst)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/expand.htm) tool.

[Polygon to raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/how-polygon-to-raster-works.htm) tool's algoritm restricted to add new raster cell if feature overlaps the cell by more than 50 percents. So you just lose raster cells that covered by feature less that 50%. You could try to make your own rasterization algorithm but it's hard.

[Quantization error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_%28signal_processing%29) appears when you try to split continual signal (your round polygon) into segments (raster image). The more your segment (pixel size), the more error. You can not fully eliminate that error because original signal is continuous, but you can make this error very small in comparison with signals period.

Comment: for the benefit our users (myself included), could you please provide a bit more detail about the quantization error you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: As of now, need to expand the cell by 1, alternatively can create my own array and convert to raster as suggested here https://geonet.esri.com/thread/177124

Comment: @Nxaunxau Added new information as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The **Polygon to Raster tool** is behaving as expected. For the areas you have highlighted in red - the cell centers are outside your data area and are given a no_data value in the output raster. The tool builds the raster from the lower left corner of the feature envelope.

You could build a simple model like the one below to (**assuming all cells representing your polygon will have the same value**):
[image]

With your polygon as the input,

1. Connect it to the Feature Envelope to Polgyon Tool
2. Generate a grid - using the Grid Index Feature Tool (set polygon size to desired cell size). Input from step 1.
3. Make Feature Layer. Input from step 2.
4. Select Layer By Location. Result from step 3 as input feature and your input polygon as the selecting feature
5. Copy Features (save to disk if required) otherwise connect output from step 4 to step 6.
6. Polygon to raster (specify value field and cell size).

Step 4 will give you something like this:
[image]

and step 6:

[image]

Add an extra step to control the values of your output raster

Comment: The same problem remain when I used 10 x 10 in Step 6 above. But I learn something new following your steps.